# payment gateway

Tags: payments, payment-gateway

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some options for taking payments on my website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/45/what-are-some-options-for-taking-payments-on-my-website)

What's a good payment gateway for an e-commerce shop with revenues of about 10.000 euros per week ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Website payments standard is fine... 
its essentially a regular merchant account with some paypal add ons.

I would suggest getting a real merchant account.
From a bank or a rep that offers them.
In the USA paysimple and braintreemerchants have great reputations.

The merchant account usually will have a preferred gateway.  The most popular is authorize.net, USAepay is a great choice also.  The gateway is really a virtual front end to the merchant account.  Allows you to process cards through a user interface or a programming interface.

The reason to go with a real merchant account now is although you may pay a bit more in fees than paypal, in the long run you could save money.  The industry of payments is changing and it will not be tough to re-negotiate your rates wiht  your merchant account or switch to someone that offers "interchange-plus-pricing" for their merchant accounts.

Comment: Seeing that he specified his weekly revenue in euros, he probably doesn't qualify for Authorize.net, which only serves U.S. businesses.

Comment: is payments standard enough for 10.000 euros per week ? Yes, I'm in Europe. Only Paypal standard works.

Comment: I think if you are doing 10k euros a week you should look for a real merchant account.  Payments standard is good if you are doing $2000 dollars a month or less.  Its real challenge is that you dont really get the detailed information on any of your transactions, also your customers leave your site to make their purchase through paypal.  You are in essence in the mercy of paypal.

Comment: With a regular merchant account, you can choose whatever gateway you like, (authorize.net, usaepay, plugnpay, etc),  so, lets say you have a merchant account with UBS bank, you can use the gateway of your choice.  If you get better rates in a year from DTZ bank then you can switch merchant accounts, keeping the same gateway, with no downtime.  this is impossible to do even with website payments pro.

Comment: Paypal makes it easy with clear fees, and decent programmer support, but the limits in my opinion are not worth it.  Getting a merchant account in the UK should not be hard.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal because:

- Setup fee None
- Monthly fee £20
- Transaction fee 1.4-3.4% per transaction + 20p (1.9% in your circumstance for 10,000 euros pw)

See my answer [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-do-i-take-payments-on-my-website/2711#2711).

Comment: do you mean Paypal Standard Payment ? The only one available in Europe ? Isn't 10.000 per week too big amount for paypal payment standard ? thanks

Comment: No I'm referring to "WEBSITE PAYMENTS PRO". Why do you not investigate this yourself? You obviously have not spent much time looking into this yourself and wish for others to give you all the answers!

Comment: 3.4% per transaction is a bit high. 10k euros per week is definitely enough to consider getting a merchant account and access to a credit card processing gateway. Usually the minimum monthly transaction fee is around $25, so paying ~$0.10 per transaction is going to be much more affordable than paying a percentage (unless you're accepting thousands of micropayments).

Comment: Website Payment Pro is not available in Europe, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal works only with 'good' countries. exUSSR countries Arabic and African countries can just pay. https://www.paypal.com/worldwide/

Comment: I think paypal is cool with some ex USSR countries like slovakia and latvia.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Gogopay Payment Gateway](http://www.gogopay.com) where rates of transaction for European customers in 2.6% and payouts for merchants are done weekly. They accept major credit cards and also net banks from Denmark.